# How to properly serialize and unserialize arrays from a mysql table(errors)

Tags: php, serialization

I have been trying to put together some code that gets an array from a MySQL table, adds a value to the array, and updates the array to the MySQL table.

The errors I recieve are the following:
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

```
    //Getting a id from a mysql table
                $rand1_user_id = $rand1['user_id'];
    //Selecting data from the row where id="$rand1_user_id"
                $rand1_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$rand1_user_id'" );
                $rand1_array = mysqli_fetch_array($rand1_id);
    //Stating array variable
                $array = array();
    //Unserialize the needed array from mysql table while saving it to $array
                $array = unserialize($rand1_array['installer_id']);

    //Adding a variable to $array
                array_push($array, $user_id);

    //Converting array back into serialized so I can add it back into the table
                $array_serialized = serialize($array);
    //Updating the table by adding the serialized array
                $add_array = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE user SET installer_id='$array_serialized' WHERE id='$rand1_user_id");
```

Comment: You're missing a `'` (single-quote) at the end of your `UPDATE` query `"UPDATE user SET installer_id='$array_serialized' WHERE id='$rand1_user_id'"` but I advise using a prepared statement with parameters instead.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @fyrye Can you elaborate on what you mean by using prepared statements with parameters? Thank you for your help!

Comment: see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for your specific use case, and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for the general information.

Comment: @fyrye I forgot to add the errors to my question, they are up now. Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error, use `var_dump($rand1_array['installer_id']);`  above the `unserialize` function call to see what it's retrieving from the database, or check the database record.

Comment: @fyrye I am getting string(1) "0"  which is the correct value from the table, but the value doesn't get updated.

Comment: Okay, `"0"` is not a serialized value, so it can not be unserialized. It would need to be `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}` in the database to be a serialized array with a single 0. You would need to check `if (!$array = @unserialize($rand1_array['installer_id'])){ $array = array(); }`

Comment: @fyrye It worked. Thanks a lot.